# How to close window in Firefox 21

Tags: javascript, firefox

I've got a "Close Button" in a web game. And if the user clicks on it the browser-window should close. But it doesn't work on Firefox version 21. In other browsers like chrome, IE work this:

```
<input type="button" class = "finish" value="Close Game" onclick="closeWindow()" />
 function closeWindow() {
 var win = window.open('', '_self');
 win.location.href = "#";
 win.close();
 }
```

Is it possible to get this working on Firefox?

Many Thanks

Comment: As a user, visit `about:config`, and add a boolean `dom. allow_scripts_to_close_windows`, set it to `true` ([more info](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_:_FAQs_:_About:config_Entries#DOM.)). As a developer, forget it. You cannot force the page to be closed in a user's browser.

Comment: I do not see anywhere outside an intranet where you would ever need to close the user's main browser. If you opened the window using `windowObject=window.open(...)`, you can close it with `windowObject.close()` and that is the only place you should try it